# composer error when i am installing zend-form

Tags: zend-framework, composer-php

```
C:\wamp64\www\zend_task>composer require zendframework/zend-form --dev
Using version ^2.14 for zendframework/zend-form
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
  Problem 1
    - Conclusion: don't install zendframework/zend-form 2.14.1
    - Conclusion: don't install zendframework/zend-form 2.14.0
    - Conclusion: don't install zendframework/zend-form 2.15.x-dev
    - Conclusion: remove zendframework/zend-filter 2.7.2
    - Conclusion: don't install zendframework/zend-filter 2.7.2**
    - zendframework/zend-inputfilter 2.10.0 requires zendframework/zend-filter ^2.9.1 -> satisfiable by zendframework/zend-filter[2.9.1, 2.10.x-dev, 2.9.x-dev].
    - zendframework/zend-inputfilter 2.9.0 requires zendframework/zend-filter ^2.9.1 -> satisfiable by zendframework/zend-filter[2.9.1, 2.10.x-dev, 2.9.x-dev].
    - zendframework/zend-inputfilter 2.9.1 requires zendframework/zend-filter ^2.9.1 -> satisfiable by zendframework/zend-filter[2.9.1, 2.10.x-dev, 2.9.x-dev].
    - zendframework/zend-inputfilter 2.11.x-dev requires zendframework/zend-filter ^2.9.1 -> satisfiable by zendframework/zend-filter[2.9.1, 2.10.x-dev, 2.9.x-dev].
    - zendframework/zend-inputfilter 2.10.x-dev requires zendframework/zend-filter ^2.9.1 -> satisfiable by zendframework/zend-filter[2.9.1, 2.10.x-dev, 2.9.x-dev].
    - Can only install one of: zendframework/zend-filter[2.9.1, 2.7.2].
    - Can only install one of: zendframework/zend-filter[2.10.x-dev, 2.7.2].
    - Can only install one of: zendframework/zend-filter[2.9.x-dev, 2.7.2].
    - Conclusion: don't install zendframework/zend-inputfilter 2.7.6|install zendframework/zend-inputfilter 2.10.0|install zendframework/zend-inputfilter 2.9.0|install zendframework/zend-inputfilter 2.9.1|install zendframework/zend-inputfilter 2.11.x-dev|install zendframework/zend-inputfilter 2.10.x-dev
    - Conclusion: don't install zendframework/zend-form 2.14.1|remove zendframework/zend-inputfilter 2.7.6|install zendframework/zend-inputfilter 2.10.0|install zendframework/zend-inputfilter 2.9.0|install zendframework/zend-inputfilter 2.9.1|install zendframework/zend-inputfilter 2.11.x-dev|install zendframework/zend-inputfilter 2.10.x-dev
    - Conclusion: don't install zendframework/zend-form 2.14.1|don't install zendframework/zend-inputfilter 2.7.6|install zendframework/zend-inputfilter 2.10.0|install zendframework/zend-inputfilter 2.9.0|install zendframework/zend-inputfilter 2.9.1|install zendframework/zend-inputfilter 2.11.x-dev|install zendframework/zend-inputfilter 2.10.x-dev
    - Conclusion: don't install zendframework/zend-form 2.14.1|remove zendframework/zend-inputfilter 2.7.6|install zendframework/zend-inputfilter 2.10.0|install zendframework/zend-inputfilter 2.9.0|install zendframework/zend-inputfilter 2.9.1|install zendframework/zend-inputfilter 2.11.x-dev|install zendframework/zend-inputfilter 2.10.x-dev
    - Conclusion: don't install zendframework/zend-form 2.14.1|don't install zendframework/zend-inputfilter 2.7.6|install zendframework/zend-inputfilter 2.10.0|install zendframework/zend-inputfilter 2.9.0|install zendframework/zend-inputfilter 2.9.1|install zendframework/zend-inputfilter 2.11.x-dev|install zendframework/zend-inputfilter 2.10.x-dev
    - Conclusion: don't install zendframework/zend-form 2.14.0|remove zendframework/zend-inputfilter 2.7.6|install zendframework/zend-inputfilter 2.10.0|install zendframework/zend-inputfilter 2.9.0|install zendframework/zend-inputfilter 2.9.1|install zendframework/zend-inputfilter 2.11.x-dev|install zendframework/zend-inputfilter 2.10.x-dev
    - Conclusion: don't install zendframework/zend-form 2.14.0|don't install zendframework/zend-inputfilter 2.7.6|install zendframework/zend-inputfilter 2.10.0|install zendframework/zend-inputfilter 2.9.0|install zendframework/zend-inputfilter 2.9.1|install zendframework/zend-inputfilter 2.11.x-dev|install zendframework/zend-inputfilter 2.10.x-dev
    - Conclusion: don't install zendframework/zend-form 2.14.0|remove zendframework/zend-inputfilter 2.7.6|install zendframework/zend-inputfilter 2.10.0|install zendframework/zend-inputfilter 2.9.0|install zendframework/zend-inputfilter 2.9.1|install zendframework/zend-inputfilter 2.11.x-dev|install zendframework/zend-inputfilter 2.10.x-dev
    - Conclusion: don't install zendframework/zend-form 2.14.0|don't install zendframework/zend-inputfilter 2.7.6|install zendframework/zend-inputfilter 2.10.0|install zendframework/zend-inputfilter 2.9.0|install zendframework/zend-inputfilter 2.9.1|install zendframework/zend-inputfilter 2.11.x-dev|install zendframework/zend-inputfilter 2.10.x-dev
    - Conclusion: don't install zendframework/zend-form 2.15.x-dev|remove zendframework/zend-inputfilter 2.7.6|install zendframework/zend-inputfilter 2.10.0|install zendframework/zend-inputfilter 2.9.0|install zendframework/zend-inputfilter 2.9.1|install zendframework/zend-inputfilter 2.11.x-dev|install zendframework/zend-inputfilter 2.10.x-dev
    - Conclusion: don't install zendframework/zend-form 2.15.x-dev|don't install zendframework/zend-inputfilter 2.7.6|install zendframework/zend-inputfilter 2.10.0|install zendframework/zend-inputfilter 2.9.0|install zendframework/zend-inputfilter 2.9.1|install zendframework/zend-inputfilter 2.11.x-dev|install zendframework/zend-inputfilter 2.10.x-dev
    - Installation request for zendframework/zend-filter (locked at 2.7.2) -> satisfiable by zendframework/zend-filter[2.7.2].
    - Conclusion: don't install zendframework/zend-form 2.15.x-dev|remove zendframework/zend-inputfilter 2.7.6|install zendframework/zend-inputfilter 2.10.0|install zendframework/zend-inputfilter 2.9.0|install zendframework/zend-inputfilter 2.9.1|install zendframework/zend-inputfilter 2.11.x-dev|install zendframework/zend-inputfilter 2.10.x-dev
    - Conclusion: don't install zendframework/zend-form 2.15.x-dev|don't install zendframework/zend-inputfilter 2.7.6|install zendframework/zend-inputfilter 2.10.0|install zendframework/zend-inputfilter 2.9.0|install zendframework/zend-inputfilter 2.9.1|install zendframework/zend-inputfilter 2.11.x-dev|install zendframework/zend-inputfilter 2.10.x-dev
    - Installation request for zendframework/zend-form ^2.14 -> satisfiable by zendframework/zend-form[2.14.0, 2.14.1, 2.15.x-dev, 2.14.x-dev].
    - Conclusion: remove zendframework/zend-inputfilter 2.7.6|install zendframework/zend-inputfilter 2.10.0|install zendframework/zend-inputfilter 2.9.0|install zendframework/zend-inputfilter 2.9.1|install zendframework/zend-inputfilter 2.11.x-dev|install zendframework/zend-inputfilter 2.10.x-dev
    - zendframework/zend-form 2.14.x-dev requires zendframework/zend-inputfilter ^2.8 -> satisfiable by zendframework/zend-inputfilter[2.10.0, 2.8.0, 2.8.1, 2.8.2, 2.8.3, 2.9.0, 2.9.1, 2.11.x-dev, 2.10.x-dev].
    - Can only install one of: zendframework/zend-inputfilter[2.8.0, 2.7.6].
    - Can only install one of: zendframework/zend-inputfilter[2.8.1, 2.7.6].
    - Can only install one of: zendframework/zend-inputfilter[2.8.2, 2.7.6].
    - Can only install one of: zendframework/zend-inputfilter[2.8.3, 2.7.6].
    - Installation request for zendframework/zend-inputfilter (locked at 2.7.6) -> satisfiable by zendframework/zend-inputfilter[2.7.6].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

Comment: Unreadable. Could you share what you tried? Could you format your error log?

Comment: How does your `composer.json` file look like before you run this command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you already have some of the dependencies installed in an older version:

```
- Conclusion: remove zendframework/zend-filter 2.7.2
- Installation request for zendframework/zend-filter (locked at 2.7.2) -> satisfiable by zendframework/zend-filter[2.7.2].
- Installation request for zendframework/zend-inputfilter (locked at 2.7.6) -> satisfiable by zendframework/zend-inputfilter[2.7.6].
```

**In order to install `zend-form` you will have to update the conflicting dependencies.**

You can either try `composer require zendframework/zend-form zendframework/zend-filter ...` to explicitly update each dependency as well, adding each new dependency that comes up on the way, until it is resolved.

Alternatively you can use one of these options:

```
--update-with-dependencies      Allows inherited dependencies to be updated, except those that are root requirements.
--update-with-all-dependencies  Allows all inherited dependencies to be updated, including those that are root requirements.
```

So for example:

```
composer require --update-with-all-dependencies zendframework/zend-form --dev
```

This is the more "drastic" option as it also updates root dependencies, which are arguably more dangerous as they directly influence your code, whereas for the other updates ideally your libraries should ensure that they can work with the selected version and you should not directly use them yourself.

This might update more dependencies than you expect and can lead to side effects. Be sure to have a clean git history and a working test suite, to make sure the update did not break anything. You should be able to see from the output or the changes in your composer.lock which dependencies where updated. This can also help identify hot spots for testing to the parts of your application that use these dependencies.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The issue has fixed with composer update command .